# Will I be missing anything in Steam VR if I use an Oculus Rift S?

Tags: oculus-rift, steam-vr

I have used the PSVR headset a lot on my PC with Steam thinking that it is a Vive.

Now I want something a bit better and given the price of the Valve Index and Vive Pro its the Rift S I am looking at getting.

I can see that compatibility with games is good with the rift on Steam so I am happy about that but would I be missing out on anything by not getting a Valve marketed "Steam VR" headset?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having had a few weeks experience with the Rift S on Steam now I feel I can answer my own question.

From my experience Steam VR plays nicely with the headset in all aspects.

Here's a list of Steam components that I can confirm work with the headset.

- Steam VR Collectables
- Steam VR Settings (You do not need to set your boundries as the ones set up in the 
  rift software still work in Steam VR games.)
- Steam VR Home
- Valves own VR title (The Lab)

So I must conclude as mentioned the experience (hardware differences aside) is no different to having a Valve marketed headset.

Answer (score 0):

Steam have been sure to make it so that it's software works with the Rift S even before it's public release. You'll have to look into it yourself as there are a few things people use specifically to avoid using SteamVR to play Steam games.